# Is this the right way to power a 12V LED and Raspberry Pi from the same 12V power source?

Tags: mosfet, led, circuit-design, dc-dc-converter, step-down

So I am trying to control an LED with a Raspberry Pi.  It's a 12V LED, and the RPi needs 5V.

From the research I have done so far, it looks like a good way to do this would be to use the GPIO port on the RPi to control a mosfet, which would allow me to modulate the voltage going to the LED, and therefore the brightness.

I would like to power both the LED and the RPi from the same 12V power source.

So my thought is, I would put a buck converter in series with the RPi to bring the voltage down, and wire this whole circuit in parallel with the LED and the mosfet.

I have tried to map out what I am describing in a circuit diagram here (very new to this so apologies if I have made errors):

[image]

1. Is this the correct approach?  Or else how can I achieve this?
2. If this is correct, how do I calculate which type of mosfet I need?

Comment: yes it will be fine. use a logic level mosfet that 3.3v from the pi turns on, like an irlz44, and swap the fet and LED (low-side switching w/ n-channel FETs)

Comment: LEDs do not vary their brightness well by changing the voltage.  The most common way of modulating the brightness of an LED is with pulse width modulation or PWM.  Most microcontrollers including the RPi have PWM output pins that make this quick and easy to do.

Comment: @jwh20 how would I use the PWM output from the RPi to power the 12V LED?  I thought the RPi could only output 5V, so wouldn't the PWM only allow between 0-5V output?  Or do you mean I should use the PWM output from the RPi to control the mosfet?

Comment: You need a resistor in series with the LED to control the LED current.  The Pi output controls the MOSFET, and the MOSFET then switches the LED current off and on.

Comment: Actually the RPi outputs are 3.3V not 5V.  Be sure you don't input voltages above 3.3V or you may damage your Pi.  The outputs will switch between ~0V and ~3.3V.  The duty cycle of a PWM waveform controls the LED brightness very linearly.  A 100% duty cycle will get you 100% brightness.  A 50% duty cycle will get you 50% brightness.  Be sure to current limit the current through the LED to avoid burning it out.  Check your LEDs specs for max current.

Comment: There are many many examples of RPi LED PWM driver circuits and software examples.  Look at this one to start: https://www.mbtechworks.com/projects/raspberry-pi-pwm.html

Comment: Also note that an RPi is capable of driving an LED directly through a resistor without the need for an external transistor.  There is also not really any such thing as a "12V LED".  LEDs generally require 2.5V (more or less) to turn on fully.

Comment: @jwh20 I don't understand what you mean about the 2.5V - this is the LED in question (COB): https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1000006354595.html?spm=a2g0o.9042311.0.0.6fee4c4dooVunC

And the voltage specified is 12-14V.  I have tested with a power supply, and it doesn't produce any light below 10V or so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work provided you move the MOSFET to the other side of the LED, so its source is at ground, and you use a current limiting resistor so as not to blow up your LED or MOSFET.

Ensure that you are using a logic-level MOSFET that will be fully turned on by 3.3 V.